# Which architectures are Harvard and which are Von Neumann?

Tags: architecture, cpu, cpu-architecture, von-neumann, harvard-architecture

I was trying to figure out which of the following architectures can be classified as Harvard (either 'strict Harvard' or modified Harvard, as long as instructions cannot be fetched from data memory, the other way around is fine) and which as Von Neumann and was hoping someone here could help me out / correct me where I'm wrong:

- Motorola 68k: It's unclear to me whether 68k is a (modified) Harvard or Von Neumann architecture.
- PPC: This one's similarly unclear to me
- AVR: All AVR architectures seem to be modified Harvard if I'm not mistaken
- PIC: The PIC microcontrollers (PIC10 to PIC24) seem to be Harvard while PIC32 seem to be Von Neumann (MIP32-based)
- SuperH: Only SH-2A and SH-4 seem to be Harvard
- 8051: Seems to be Harvard as well

Answer (score 4):

**Abbreviations**

> VNA = Von Neumann Architecture
>   HVA = Harvard Architecture
>   MHVA = Modified HVA

- **Motorola 68k** is *VNA*, it has a single memory for program and data.
- **PowerPC** is *VNA*, it has a single memory for program and data.
- **AVR** is *MHVA* because it has separate program and data memory and the `LPM` instruction can be used to load data from program memory.
- **PIC16** is *HVA* because it has separate program and data memory and no instruction to read from program memory.
- **SuperH** are usually *VNA* but some DSP models are *HVA*.
- **8051** is *MHVA* because it has separate program and data memory and the `MOVC` instruction can be used to load data from program memory.

Comment: PIC can [read and write program memory](https://microchipdeveloper.com/16bit:accessing-flash-memory) so it's actually MHVA